# Printing Balanced Partition

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

There are two arrays , say A & B. There are n entries in each of them , now we want to get minimum difference if we select either of each A & B for for ith entry. Exact problem [here](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/EQGIFTS) .

I have done that problem,now if we add to print the the distribution ,then how to proceed ? We need to print A or B on every ith line depending that which of A or B we choose .
Ex:n=4
A:3,7 ,8,3
B:5,11,8,9

Then we need to print AAAB , we get diff. as 1.